# How to get MYSQL Duplicate error for multiple unique column

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling

I am trying to get error message or code for my sql query i currently have my method as this in a class file

```
public function createNew()
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " SET userId = ?, email = ?, data1 = ?";

        $obj = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $this->userId = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->userId));
        $this->email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
        $this->data1 = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->data1));
        $obj->bind_param("sss", $this-> userId, $this->email, $this->data1);
        if ($obj->execute()) {return true;}
        return false;
    }
```

And here is the php file

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

        $users->userId = $data->userId;
        $users->email = $data->email;
        $users->data1 = $data->data1;
        if ($users->createNew()) {
            http_response_code(200);
            echo json_encode(array(
                "status" => 200,
                "message" => "Success"
            ));
        } else {
            http_response_code(200);
            echo json_encode(array(
                "status" => 500,
                "message" => "Failed"
            ));
        }
    }
```

The code currently work fine but when a duplicate value is insert for email or userId i get error message as

```
"message" => "Failed"
```

but what i want is the specific error that is when userId is duplicated the error message should be userId already exists or if it the email then the message should be email already exists instead of all the error returning Failed.
Thanks

Comment: Side note : do not store data using htmlspecialchars. you should escape only on display.

Comment: Thanks any idea how to implement that am fairly new to PHP

Comment: In createNew function. When $obj->excute() return false; -> try debug print_r($obj->errorInfo());

Comment: i edited my comment.

Comment: @MaiTruong Thanks now am getting  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt: :errorInfo()

Comment: please see my answer and try debug with  mysql_error()

Comment: You simply could check if the user exists with a "SELECT" query before to insert. If the user already exists, return your specific error.

Comment: It seems you are using mysqli. That extension doesn't report errors by default, you need to do it yourself. Ideally, make it throw exceptions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/13508